# What is wrong with this number script?

Tags: javascript, html, numbers

I'm very new to JavaScript and I want to do an input check.
Here is my script:

```
function checkInp()
{
  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["num"].value; // Get the value
  if (isNaN(x)) 
  {
    alert("Not a number!"); // Check if the input is a number
    return false;
  }
  var valuex=document.forms["myForm"]["num"].value; // Get the value, i don't know if i have to re-write this variable, if no, please comment.
  Number(valuex); // Make the input a number
  if (valuex.value > 480) {
    alert("Too high!"); // See if the number is greater than 480. If yes, say that, if not, return normally.
    return false;
  } 
  else {
    return;
  }
}
```

I don't know what happens, but the script doesn't work since I added the second part (to check if the number is greater than 480).
Please help me, with full example if possible.

Comment: Why are you voting down? Is there a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'll doing it:

- Document selectorQuery is more understandable
- Dont get the value multiple time
- Use ParseInt to transform your var on number
- Don't forget to return true if success

Code:

```
function checkInp() {
  var x = document.querySelector('input[name="num"]').value;  
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    alert("Must be a number");
    return false
  } else if (x > 480) {
    alert("Must be under 480");
    return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: Note that `parseInt()` is for **integers**, and also that it allows trailing non-numeric garbage (so "123hello world" is accepted).

Comment: `!0` is true, and 0 is definitely a Number. better check for `isNaN(x)` or `x !== x`. `NaN` is the only value in JS that is not equal to itself

Comment: Pointy and Thomas, you both right, I updated my code

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong, i thnk you need just to do like this:

```
If(valuex > 480)..
```